# Can't go to next page with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to move on to the next page after scraping an eventsbrite page but it isn't working even after using Scrapy's Crawlspider.

here's the code to traverse the pages

```
 allowed_domains = ["eventbrite.com"]
start_urls = ["https://www.eventbrite.com/d/nigeria--lagos/events/?crt=regular&end_date=01%2F31%2F2018&page=1&sort=best&start_date=12%2F01%2F2017",
]    
 def parse(self, response):
    events = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="list-card-v2 l-mar-top-2 js-d-poster"]')

    for event in events:
        name = event.xpath('a/div[@class="list-card__body"]/div[@class="list-card__title"]/text()').extract()
        venue = event.xpath('a/div[@class="list-card__body"]/div[@class="list-card__venue"]/text()').extract()
        date = event.xpath('a/div[@class="list-card__body"]/time[@class="list-card__date"]/text()').extract()
        event_type = event.xpath('a/div[@class="list-card__header"]/span/text()').extract()
        category = event.xpath('div/div[@class="list-card__tags"]/a/text()').extract()
        image= event.xpath('a/div[@class="list-card__header"]/div/img[@class="js-poster-image"]').extract()
        image_url= event.xpath('a/div[@class="list-card__header"]/div/img[@class="js-poster-image"]/@src').extract()

        name = ''.join(name).replace('\n', '').strip()
        date = ''.join(date).replace('\n', '').strip()
        venue = ''.join(venue).replace('\n', '').strip()


        yield EventsItem(name=name, venue=venue, date=date,
                         event_type=event_type, category=category,
                         image_urls=image_url, images=image)

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@data-automation="next-page"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

here's an image of the the element. I dont know if it's because the href attribute is empty or a wrong xpath.

[image: Image of next page html element]

Any help is welcomed, thank you.

Comment: it seems this portal uses JavaScript to change page - but Scrapy doesn't execute JavaScript. You will have to use Selenium to control web browser which will run JavaScript. Or create url manually - it should be always similar and you may have to only change page number in this url.

Comment: I checked page and it use JavaScript to load another page but next page use almost the same url - you have to only change `page=1` to `page=2` and later `page=3`, etc.

Comment: BTW: If you use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox then you will see that this portal use url https://www.eventbrite.com/directory/json?page=2&cat=&subcat=&format=&q=&loc=Lagos%2C+Lagos&date=&start_date=12%2F01%2F2017&end_date=01%2F31%2F2018&is_paid=&sort=best&crt=regular&slat=&slng=&radius=&vp_ne_lat=&vp_ne_lng=&vp_sw_lat=&vp_sw_lng=  to get next page as `JSON` which Python can easily convert to dictionary and you will not have to load HTML. If you change `page=2` to `page=3` in this url then you get third page as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

In place of the last line which is:

```
yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Try this one:

```
yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

Note:
Be careful about the allowed URLs. In some cases they should not contain `http` or `https`. In those cases use, for example, `google.com` instead of `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: I have edited this answer a little. The words after "Note:" were not clear so I have made some changes. If I have mid-understood what you intended then please [edit] the answer to correct it.